# Any substitution for the negative lookahead in regular expression?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm using regular expression to extract some country data in BigQuery. And I don't know how to extract the text I want from it. This is the example records I use.

| country |
| --- |
| China Anhui Univ Chinese Med, Affiliated Hosp 1, Expt Ctr Clin Res, Sci Res Dept, 117 Meishan Rd, Hefei 230031, Anhui, 12, Peoples R China |
| Meluna Res, Geldermalsen, Netherlands; [Wiegant, Frederik Anton Clemens] Univ Utrecht, Utrecht, Netherlands |

I wanted to extract the last comma-followed words `Peoples R China`, `Netherlands` from the text, so I used the negative lookahead to extract them.

```
(, )(?!.*\b\1\b)((\w*\s?){3})
```

But it seems like BigQuery doesn't support lookahead expressions since they only support RE2.
Is there any way I can extract the country name without using lookahead expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```sql
,\s*([^,]*)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KuzMEd/1). The pattern matches

- `,` - a comma
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^,]*)` - capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than a comma
- `$` - end of string.